# Save changes after applying Dom Manipulation with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am working on a dynamic page. I just came to the idea that text of some DOM elements on my pages should be editable  i.e the text of buttons, label and paragraphs etc.

Is there any way to save the the manipulated DOM with JavaScript/jQuery so that my DOM changes remain persistent?

Note: I am working on dynamic pages not static pages I know if it was static pages then it is easy to save the manipulated DOM by **Save as Html** in the context menu.

I don't want to use any framework other than jQuery.

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp . If this is not what you need please provide an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yeah i can also use the local storage , but the changes would not be persistent as local storage can be removed easily.

Comment: Or can you save the HTML string into your DB and render it from there...

Comment: there is no easy way to do this

Comment: The only alternative is to store the info server-side. We will need a more concrete example of what are you doing. Who can edit the DOM? What happens if more than one visitor edits the DOM? etc

Comment: @wong2 yeah it is not easy , is it possible to do this functionality ?? or is there any js framework for this problem ??

Comment: Local storage seems like it's exactly what you're needing to use.  It would be a security issue if you couldn't remove client-side stored data easily.  Otherwise, you're stuck with server sessions and storing in your server DB

Comment: @JosephMarikle I agree with your solution but i don't want any complex solution. How about listing the values in a js file in json formate   and saving/overwriting  the file on server side ???

Comment: What about concurrent edits by different users? You'd need a giant file saving each user's settings, or one file per user. Storing in DB seems the simplest solution.

Comment: @Sebastianb thanx for reflecting toward the concurrent  edits issues. Now Local storage seems the best solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can as pointed out by comments save the user's changes in the browser. But as soon as the user clears the cache, these changes will be lost. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)

If I understand correctly what you want to do, you should make an ajax call after each change in order to save the new value of the label, paragraph or whatever you modified, in your database.

You can do it with native javascript or with jquery (though the jquery syntax is easier to read: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

well what i get is you want your user to change the content of your page,a simple implementation would be to create a function that record all the changes of that specific section ,and then on save it post data via ajax to your server, which saves the page state,

consider the following example

```
<div class="comment" data-cid="3344">
     <div class="comment-text">my comment i want to change</div>
     <ul>
       <li class="edit">edit</li>
       <li class="del">delete</li>
     </ul>


</div>
```

and in js

```
     $('.edit').click(function(){
           var ul = $(this).parent();
           var comment = ul.parent();
           comment.find(".comment-text").attr("contentEditable","true");
           ul.append("<li class="save">save</li>")

           comment.find('.save').click(function(){
                   new data = {
                     value:comment.find("comment-text").html(), 
                     cid: comment.data("cid")  
                   }


                   $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                      url: url,
                      data: data,
                      success: function(returndata){alert(saved)},
                      dataType: dataType
                    });
           }); // save click
   });
```

in php

```
<?php 
// check if session
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password); 

// consider you have a comment active record pattern implemented !!
$c = new comment;
comment->load($_POST["cid"]);
comment->setValue($_POST["value"]);
comment->save();
```

now this is a simple but not so particle demonstration, you can add all type of complexity , like handling sessions , or from-keys, or not even exposing the cid to the front-end..